# How to add outline to text in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, text

I'm a newcomer to text programming in iOS and a bit stumped at the moment. I am creating an example project to learn how to make a lolcat app (start with something fun!).

I have a UIImage with the cat and I'm putting some text on top of it by having a UITextView on top with text.

I'd like to end up with something like this for the text:

[image: lolcat]

I was able to successfully pull this off when I had the text in a UILabel. I used code I found on SO that used `drawTextInRect` to accomplish the magic.

Now, I'd like to do the same thing in the UITextView (I want to be able to scroll the text).

**EDIT: ** so here is what I'm trying so far:

```
var foo = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : NSNumber(float: -4.0),
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30.0)
 ])
```

That gets me a result like this:

[image]

If I now double the stroke width to -8.0 I get the below result which looks pretty darn bad in my estimation. It seems like there is a tradeoff between the stroke width and how much of the fill I can see. Ideally I'd like the stroke to just get wider without eating up the white text.

[image]

Comment: Please note: if you're going to downvote my question, you should leave a comment explaining why. Downvotes without comments do nothing to edify me.

Comment: "My problem is that UITextView of course doesn't provide the same hooks as UILabel" I don't see what you mean. They both allow you to use an NSAttributedString, and with an NSAttributedString, this is easy.

Comment: The title and content of your question are a little unrelated. The title is asking how to create outline text, but the content seems to me asking how to draw text on top of image. Please rephrase it to make it more clear.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on NSAttributedString. You can give letters an outline stroke:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes

Use the `NSStrokeColorAttributeName` and `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` to configure the outline stroke.

Once you have your attributed string you can put it an a label, put it in a text view, or draw it directly, as you please.

[image]

Might look a little better if you add some expansion and a tiny bit of shadow:

[image]

Comment: I mentioned in my post that this is on iOS but you've linked me to the Mac developer docs. Thank you for the info though!

Comment: @bitops It's exactly the same on iOS.

Comment: are you sure that this works the way you expect? When I try to plug this in, the stroke "eats" the character the wider I make it. I want the stroke to go around the outside of the character.

Comment: @bitops Added an image. I don't think it's so bad.

Comment: I'll post an update to my question - I'm not seeing similar results to what you're getting in your image.

Comment: @bitops Not saying it's totally just like the posters, just saying it's not terrible.

Comment: @bitops you're using a crappy font, for one thing; you need a font with some heft

Comment: Have you tried a different weight for the font. Seems like making it Bold might do the trick. If that is not an option, choose a font that is more favorable with a heavy weight as suggested by Matt.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the help of library [DrawingLabel](https://github.com/selim1377/DrawingLabel) without any CoreGraphics code

```
DrawingStroke *blackStroke = [DrawingStroke new];
blackStroke.strokeWidth = 3.0;
blackStroke.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```